# Annoying IE6. Black screen with "loading" when youtube is added

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, joomla, youtube

I have had this problem for quite some time. It wasn't  actually a big issue until lately when one of our conference site has a lot of IE6 users.

The black loading screen appears right after I include a youtube clip into our site. The site is content managed with Joomla but I don't see any reason how Joomla has got any compatibility issues with youtube and IE6 !

Anyone knows how, why or has experienced this similar issue b4 ?

url of website: http://schoolcontingency.com

[image: Snapshot of website with IE Net Renderer]

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ - has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: isn't this about css and browser compatibility ?  and its also about Joomla..

Comment: Step one on your Emergency Disaster Planning should be: "uninstall IE6 to avoid a Disaster"

Comment: Tried using <!-- [if (gte IE 7)(!IE)]> <![endif]-->  but the youtube div wouldn't appear on firefox. Is the code right?

Comment: @meo I'll really love to use that.. and even considering putting up the IE6 countdown banner ! unfortunately, I'm not the president for this company...

Comment: Are you sure this happens in IE6 or are you basing this on netrenderer? I tried it in BrowserLabs and the page displays with the video missing. How are you embedding the video?