# Prevent div from loading with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, cross-browser

I'm trying to work around with the problem I have at [Annoying IE6. Black screen with "loading" when youtube is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408808/annoying-ie6-black-screen-with-loading-when-youtube-is-added)

Basically, I'm thinking of:

1. Javascript checks browser version when user
   enters.
2. If MSIE version = 6.0,
   prevents browser from loading the
   div/object that holds the youtube
   (which is the cause of the full
   black background with "loading")

I'm able to get to checking browser version, but not for the part where the code prevents the object from being loaded.

help please..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Annoying IE6. Black screen with "loading" when youtube is added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408808/annoying-ie6-black-screen-with-loading-when-youtube-is-added)

Comment: how can it be duplicate ? my previous post was about the problem. Right now I'm asking whether there's a possibility of using javascript to manipulate what will be loaded by the browser. Thats like 2 different fields.. I merely used my previous question as an example to project a better understanding towards my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert the div into the body of the page depending on the version. 
eg ie MSIE < 7 then do nothing else insert object that contains youtube video.

Comment: do you mean <!-- [IF !IE 6]> <![endif--> ?

Comment: Not I meant in JS using jquery. for eg. if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<7){//ie 6 display error msg}else{//insert object using jquery or native js}

Comment: I actually used `if (!$j.browser.msie) {
   $j("#youtube").html('hello world');
  }
  else { 
   if ($j.browser.version > 6.0 ) 
    $j("#youtube").html('hello world'); 
    
  }`

But I'm still interested to know if there's a way to notify the browser not to load the object before it starts loading the whole page.. .thanks anyway !

Comment: Not quiet sure what you after but if you have a "placeholder" with an id of "youtube" then $(document).ready() with that function your insert/load the object into your placeholder so if its not IE6 then just place some text saying "Sorry not supported" else loading in your object...simple.